# How to manipulate individual pixels in Mat image in OpenCV 3.0.0-1.1 Java API

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mat, hipi

Until now, the previous versions of OpenCV JAVA API offered `get()` and `put()` methods in order to fetch and manipulate the individual pixels in a Mat image. But in  OpenCV 3.0.0-1.1 Java API those methods are deprecated. So how can individual pixels be manipulated in this version.

Here is a list of deprecated methods:
http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/deprecated-list.html

When I'm using the `put()` method in HIPI v2.0 (which supports latest OpenCV API), I'm getting the following error:

[Image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBAie.png)

What can I do to change particular pixels (given the indices)?

Comment: please, do not confuse opencv's java wrappers with bytedeco/javacv, 2 totally seperate pair of shoes.

Comment: I'm a total newbie to HIPI and Opencv (or even image processing for that matters).i don't understand what exactly is bytedeco/javacv?bytedeco/javacpp is what hipi uses for accessing opencv methods in the new version i.e. v2.0(it has in built support for opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is via an [Indexer](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/indexer/Indexer.html) as introduced in this post:
http://bytedeco.org/news/2014/12/23/third-release/

So, for example, in the case of a typical BGR/RGB 8-bit image:

```java
UByteIndexer idx = mat.createIndexer();
idx.put(x, y, z, 255);
assert idx.get(x, y, z) == 255;
```